# Use Firestore autoID to retrieve and display data in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

im new to flutter and dont know exactly what to search for this one but, can we use the auto generated ID like in the picture to retrieve all that data UNDER that ID? if so, how ? In a similar question that I stumbled upon, they use `database.reference()` but its a Realtime Database and not FireStore

Im using Firebase Cloud Firestore

[image]

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking. Have you read through the documentation for Firestore's data model to understand how it works?  https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model

Answer (score 3):

There is no AutoId in firebase but here is a quick way to set as auto id

Forexample ;

1- create yourModel ( which one u gonna send as model to firebase )

2- `DatabaseReference firebaseDatabase;`

3- `firebaseDatabase =FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();`

4- `firebaseDatabase.child("table_name").push().set( yourModel.toJson() );`

### Also for getting data u can write code like that

```
var result= firebaseDatabase.child("table_name").once().then(
   (DataSnapshot datasnapshot){
     Map<dynamic,dynamic> values= datasnapshot.value;
     values.forEach((key,value){
       print("key:"+key+" value:"+value["name"]);
     });
   }
 );
 print(result);
```

I tried it and works great

Have a nice day !!!

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you're asking about subcollections.

If you read a document (by its (auto-generated or not) key), you get back that document. You don't get back data from any subcollection. That will require a separate read operation for each subcollection under the document that you want to read.